# Libgdx sprites displaced touching areas

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, area, sprite

when setting up the sprite buttons in my libgdx project, i get displaced their touching area if i give a screen size that is bigger than my device one.

This is a simple example of the code i wrote. The main class extends Game...

```
public class Application extends Game
    {
        public SpriteBatch batch;
        public OrthographicCamera camera;

        public Vector3 touchPosition;

        protected TitleScreen screen_title;
        protected SettingsScreen screen_settings;
        public PlayScreen screen_play;

        @Override
        public void create()
        {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();

            camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
            camera.setToOrtho(false,Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);

            touchPosition = new Vector3();

            //SCREENS
            screen_title = new TitleScreen(this);
            screen_settings = new SettingsScreen(this);
            screen_play = new PlayScreen(this);

            this.setScreen(screen_title);
        }
}
```

And a simple screen with an image to detect if is touched...

```
  public TitleScreen(final Application game)
{
    this.game = game;
    game.camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    game.camera.position.set(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH / 2, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT / 2, 0);

    background = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.PATH_BACKGROUND + "bg.png")));
    img = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")));
}

@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();

    background.draw(game.batch);
    img.setPosition( Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH / 2, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT /2);
    img.draw(game.batch);

    game.batch.end();

    //detect touch position
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        game.touchPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        game.camera.unproject(game.touchPosition);

        if ((Gdx.input.getX() > img.getX()) &&
                Gdx.input.getX() < img.getX() + img.getWidth() &&
                Gdx.input.getY() < Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - img.getY() &&
                Gdx.input.getY() > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (img.getY() + img.getHeight()))
        {
            System.out.println("TOUCHED BUTTON!!!");
            System.out.println("X: " + Gdx.input.getX() + "/ Y: " +  Gdx.input.getY());
        }
    }

}
```

As mentioned, this code sample works fine in desktop (any size) and my phone (if it has same or smaller screen size), but not when i use a bigger viewport size, and don't really understand why :)

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Touch coordinates are in screen pixels. If you use your own arbitrary viewport size that doesn't match the screen size, then the units don't match. Instead of this method, use `camera.unproject()` to convert touch coordinates to game coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, will review the camera javadoc to get the right coordinates system :)